# no WM_SIZE message when minimize or restore

Tags: winapi, mfc, wtl

According to MSDN,  WM_SIZE should be sent to window when window is minimized or restored.
But my application window, which is WTL CDialogImpl never get WM_SIZE when minimize or restore.

I use spy++ to check on it,  I can get WM_SYSCOMMAND, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANING, WM_ACTIVE, WM_ACTIVEAPP etc,  but no WM_SIZE.

I checked some other WTL example application,  I'm able to get WM_SIZE msg when minimize or restore.

My question is why my WTL CDialogImpl window doesn't receive WM_SIZE?
Besides this,   is there any other message to indicate the restore or minimize finish?
I mean,  in system, most of time, there is animation to show the minimize/restore process. I need a message or event to let app know the animation is done when restore.

thanks!

William L.

Comment: WM_MOVE, not WM_SIZE.  Document the style flags of the window.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632646%28VS.85%29.aspx) *A window receives this message through its WindowProc function* so you will not get it through Spy++.

Anyhow the **WM_SIZE** message is received in a *ATL::CDialogImpl* derived dialogs at creation, minimization and restoration.

To check it with the WTL AppWizard create a minimal WTL modal Dialog application and add a message map entry for WM_SIZE and a matching *OnSize()* member:

```
    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainDlg)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, OnSize)
        //...
    END_MSG_MAP()
    LRESULT OnSize(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        return 0;
    }
```

Set a breakpoint in OnSize() it will be hit.

Your problem (if any) is elsewhere.